# How i can implement two or three options in dropdownitem in KIVYMD

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivymd

i am trying to implement dropdownitem in my mobile app developed in kivymd framework by the documentation but it is not working properly. can you please suggest  advice anything which can be any resource and any readable stuff or your pre written code so , I can read from it and get the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, asking for tutorial etc. suggestions is off-topic

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).